# Bootstrap 5 stop span tag causing line break

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

As per other questions on this, I am trying to use `white-space:nowrap;` to stop the span tag in this text causing a line break, but not succeeding yet.

Class styles here are all Bootstrap 5 standard CSS class styles. In wider screens, the time displays below date here with the `<br/>` line break, which is what I want, but in narrow screen widths, I want this date and time appearing same line, with 3 extra spaces between date and time. Thanks if any suggestions to resolve span / line break problem here. 'carlito' class only sets font style and colour.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-12 col-md-3 carlito" style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <h4 class="text-center text-danger">Sunday 28th March 2021
    <span class="d-block d-md-none" style="display: inline-block;">   </span>
    <br class="d-none d-md-block" />11AM - 3PM </h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `span` element remove the class of `d-block`, you're changing the inline property of span element to block. That is why it's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`d-block` and `style="display:inline-block`" for the same container ? , make it simple :), use either custom style or built-in class.

is this what you need ?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-12 col-md-3 carlito" style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <h4 class="text-center text-danger">Sunday 28th March 2021
    <span class="d-inline-block d-md-none" >   </span>
    <br class="d-none d-md-block" />11AM - 3PM </h4>
</div>
```

if yes then :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-12 col-md-3 carlito" style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <h4 class="text-center text-danger">Sunday 28th March 2021
    <span class="d-inline-block d-md-block" >   
     11AM - 3PM </span></h4>
</div>
```

should be fine ;)

Comment: Thanks kindly for your help, as @Sidharth explained to me very succinctly the core of my mistake, gave him favourite. Actually, because I wanted total 4 spaces between these phrases at mobile width, but only break at desktop width, I found I needed to put  in `&nbsp;` s inside span:
`<h4 class="text-center text-danger">Sunday 28th March 2021<span class="d-inline-block d-md-none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><br class = "d-none d-md-block" />11AM - 3PM </h4>`
For other front end newbs, I found this css display options comparison helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp